# Round to the nearest number of a list

Tags: python, math, rounding

I am writing a program that returns a value between 0 and 0.25. I want to round this value to the closest of a predefined list of values.

For example given a list of

```py
round_to = [0,0.1,0.15,0.2,0.25]
```

A value of 0.004 should be rounded to 0, a value of 0.09 -> 0.1, a value of 0.126 -> 0.15, a value of 0.22 -> 0.2, and so on.

Does anyone know an elegant way to accomplish this?

Any insights are much appreciated!

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but if the numbers in that list are fixed, a simple rounding will work. `0.05*round(x/0.05)` gives the desired results. 0.05 is the gcf of your list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `min()` with a key parameter that compares entries in `round_to` based on the absolute value of the difference between each value:

```py
round_to = [0,0.1,0.15,0.2,0.25]
entry = 0.126

min(round_to, key=lambda x: abs(x - entry))
```

This outputs:

```py
0.15
```